# Can I use tensorflow v1 checkpoint at v2 without compat.v1 library?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have checkpoint files (meta, index, ckpt) from tensorflow v1. But I don't have any code like create_model so I can't load model in tensorflow v2, and load wegiths.

Is there any way to get model and load weight together in Tensorflow v2 with these files?

I found some functions like 'builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables', 'tf.saved_model.simple_save' but I think it's not useful to me.

And I tried to convert ckpt, meta to pb, and pb to h5 file but I think it's impossible.

Is there any way to use version 1 checkpoint file at version2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `tensorflow.compat.v1` with tensorflow v2 and I was able to use tensorflow v1 resources.

`model_path` is tensorflow v1 checkout path.
**I needed to find tensor name of model ("X:0", "is_trainig:0", "prob:0").**

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True


class Model:
    def __init__(self, model_path, model_name):
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        self.sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph, config=config)
        with self.graph.as_default():
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(model_path, "{}.meta".format(model_name)))
            saver.restore(self.sess, os.path.join(model_path, model_name))
            self.X = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("X:0")
            self.is_training = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("is_training:0")
            self.prob = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("prob:0")
```